# Sum of few subjects full marks out of all subject full marks in access

Tags: ms-access

I am new in this platform could you help me to resolve my problem in access.
I have subjects table like that in design view.

```
ID |  Auto number | primary key
Subjects | Short text
Full marks | Numbers
Pass marks | Number
```

Now Table In data sheet view.

```
ID    |           Subjects                 |  Full marks     |       Pass marks
1     |              English               |    100          |           33
2     |              French                |    100          |           33
3     |             Mathematics            |    100          |           33
4     |             Science                |    100          |           33
5     |             Drawing                |    50           |           17
6     |             Moral Science          |    100          |           33
7     |             Computer               |    100          |           33
8     |             Art & MD               |    100          |           33
```

Now my question is that when I created a form for data entry  don't sum ID 5 and 6  subjects full marks in total but it should be appear on the form  only their marks will not add in total. Means total marks calculate 600 not 850. How to do that.

Comment: It's a bit unclear in where you want the sum to appear. But If you simply want the sum of the table, you could use `DSUM("[Full Marks]","Table")` and plug it to whatever control you want it to appear. I could be more helpful if I knew what your intentions were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sum only records displayed on form or report, expression in textbox in header or footer section like:

`=Sum(IIf(ID<5 Or ID>6, [Full Marks], 0))`

If filter is applied to form or report, the sum will adjust.

Unfortunately, `<>` operator would not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to fully understand what you are looking to accomplish without a concrete example, but assuming that you want the `Full Marks` & `Pass Marks` for all records to appear on your form, but for the values of these fields to be excluded from the total for specific `ID` values, then you could use the following `DSum` expression when calculating the total marks:

```
=DSum("[Full Marks]", "Subjects", "ID not in (5, 6)")
```